# Finding last Index(position) of the character(#) in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string, nsstring

Want to get index of the last occurrence of # but bellow code working fine for the other character but not giving perfect result for particularity "#"

Code Working fine in viewDidLoad but not working in textfield shouldChangeCharactersInRange.

Code:

```
txtTest.text = @"@ashish @test #vijay $4030 @post";


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
   NSRange range = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"a" options:NSBackwardsSearch];        
    NSLog(@"a :: %d   ",range.location);

    range = [str rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSLog(@"@ :: %d   ",range.location);

    range = [str rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSLog(@"# :: %d",range.location);

    range = [str rangeOfString:@"$" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSLog(@"$ :: %d\n",range.location);

}
```

Result ::
a :: 17  @ :: 26   *# :: 2147483647* $ :: 20

[image]

Comment: That is `NSNotFound`. Maybe the characters looks the same but are not, or there is a zero-width space in there or some such?

Comment: Yep, there is an invisible character in your `@"#"` string. Use the arrow keys to move the cursor across it and you'll see it.

Comment: Copied and Pasted to Xcode (this may autoformat some things, maybe even encoding stuff). Fixed NSString typo on first line, runs fine.

Comment: a :: 17   
@ :: 26   
# :: 13
$ :: 20, I found this result correcting NSString spelling

Comment: @jamil When i put same code in viewDidLoad then its work fine but in shouldChangeCharactersInRange its not working.. replace "str" with string

Answer (score 8):

Try %lu unsigned long instead of %d . Its working fine

```
NSString *str = @"ashish @test #vijay $4030 @post";

NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"a" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"a :: %lu   ",(unsigned long)range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"@ :: %lu   ",(unsigned long)range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"# :: %lu",(unsigned long)range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"$" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"$ :: %lu\n",(unsigned long)range.location);
```

a :: 17

@ :: 26

# :: 13

$ :: 20

Comment: Thanks for the response and  in viewDidLoad its work fine but in shouldChangeCharactersInRange its not working

Comment: Working fine  in shouldChangeCharactersInRange too .

Comment: Strange but its not working in my machine :( i had also attached screenshot

Comment: it is showing me this random big integer in case if the charcter isn't in text field as text "ash" the logs showing a :: 0   @ :: 9223372036854775807   # :: 9223372036854775807   $ :: 9223372036854775807 . So double check your delegated and fields.

Comment: and please try to change the name of your range object , because same name NSRange object is from shouldChangeCharactersInRange method.

Comment: Yes its showing random big number when character is not present but string constance character then its working except "#" and also try NSRange object but same result

Answer (score 3):

First, you have a spelling mistake.It is `NSString *str`, not `NSSting *str`.

The rest works well on my machine.

```
NSString *str = @"ashish @test #vijay $4030 @post";

NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"a" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"a :: %lu   ",range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"@ :: %lu   ",range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"# :: %lu",range.location);

range = [str rangeOfString:@"$" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSLog(@"$ :: %lu\n",range.location);
```

answer:

```
2016-02-29 15:19:39.554 StackOverflowDemo[9189:1825956] a :: 17   
2016-02-29 15:19:39.555 StackOverflowDemo[9189:1825956] @ :: 26   
2016-02-29 15:19:39.555 StackOverflowDemo[9189:1825956] # :: 13
2016-02-29 15:19:39.555 StackOverflowDemo[9189:1825956] $ :: 20
```

Can you say more clearly?

Comment: in viewDidLoad its work fine but in shouldChangeCharactersInRange its not working :(

Comment: Did you check (and re-enter) the string as was mentioned in the comments? You do have some "non-standard" character in there, and the different locations clearly indicate that as well.